# To Make 3rd Tab in Product View Page as Active Tab

Tags: magento-community, review, product-page

I have 3 tab sections in my product page as below.

```
|  Description  |  Additional Info  |  Customer Review  |
```

Right now `Description` tab is default active tab but i want to set 3rd `Customer Review` tab as default active tab.

So how can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Magento is not providing such feature out of box. However you can make this work without creating a module actually. I will show you one of such method here.

### Step 1 : Use `local.xml` to update `detailed_info` child groups

**Explanation :** You may be wondering now, what the hell is this `detailed_info` child group ! Well it is a long story, the key point that you need to understand here is, those tabs that you are viewing in product view page in default Magento 1.9.* are actually children of `detailed_info` group. In short, you can create such block groups and set it with a parent block. Later you can collect those block group from the parent block and do whatever you want with them. In case of product view page, `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` block holds such a child group whose name is `detailed_info` (refer : `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml`) and then use this child group to create the tabs (refer : `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`)

This is the theory and now why we need to update this child group ? Good question. Well, we are now going to set a new property `active_tab` (using magic methods) in the children blocks of the group `detailed_info` so that we can later use this to determine, which is the active block (or tab) which need to be activated by default.

File : `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.description">
            <action method="setActiveTab"><active_tab>0</active_tab></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.attributes">
            <action method="setActiveTab"><active_tab>1</active_tab></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.reviews">
            <action method="setActiveTab"><active_tab>1</active_tab></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="product.view.activetab" as="active_tab" template="custom/catalog/product/view/activetab.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Here two points to note.

*Point 1:* We are updating default child blocks of the group `detailed_info` with `<action method="setActiveTab"><active_tab>0 | 1</active_tab></action>`. As you can see, review block holds 1 as its value.

*Point 2 :* You can also see a new block inclusion inside the layout update. The block which is included in the layout has name `product.view.activetab` and which is a children of `product.info` block (block which holds `detailed_info` blocks group). This block is going to hold the *default active tab logic*.

### Step 2 : Call our new block in product view block

**Explanation :** So we defined a new block via layout update. We need to call our new block manually in `view.phtml` file so that, our block get used while generating the product view page content. Let us do that.

File : `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <? /** calling our block here **/ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('active_tab') ?>
</div>
```

I have shown you where should we call our new block. All the above codes except the part `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('active_tab') ?>` is present in `view.phtml`.

### Step 3 : Include default active tab Logic via new block template

**Explanation :** Now our block is included in the product view page. It is the time to define our new block template, in order to do the "magic".

File : `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/custom/catalog/product/view/activetab.phtml`

```
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getParentBlock()->getChildGroup('detailed_info')) : ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $info) : ?>
        <?php echo $count ?>
        <?php if ($info->getActiveTab() == 1) : ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                $j(document).ready(function() {
                    var titleLists = $j('.toggle-content ul > li');
                    var DTs = $j('.toggle-content dl > dt');
                    var DDs = $j('.toggle-content dl > dd');
                    var indexNum = parseInt(<?php echo (int)$count; ?>);

                    titleLists.removeClass('current');
                    DTs.removeClass('current');
                    DDs.removeClass('current');

                    titleLists.eq(indexNum).addClass('current');
                    DTs.eq(indexNum).addClass('current');
                    DDs.eq(indexNum).addClass('current');
                });
            //]]>
            </script>
            <?php break; ?>
        <?php elseif ($info->getActiveTab() == null) : ?>
            <?php $count-- ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php $count++ ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

What we are doing here is, we will collect the `detailed_info` group, loop through the children blocks, find the active tab block and then set that tab as active by inserting a `<script />`. That's it.

Now clear the cache and load the page again. You will see the magic.

***Note :*** Please use [**my Gist for reference**](https://gist.github.com/progammer-rkt/d8c1412c824c1fba573d).

Comment: Perfect and detail answer, +1 for me. :)

Comment: superb explanation dude +1 from me @rajeev

Answer (score 0):

You can doing this `using xml`  and magento have `managing using before and after to`positioning of block type phtml

**step1:** goto `review.xm`l at app/design/frontend/rwd(yourpackage)/default(yourtemplate)/layout/

**Step2:** find  `product layout handler`  `catalog_product_view` and then find `after="additional"` **remove** that add this

```
before="-" .
```

see more layout tag http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts#head-anatomy-of-a-layout

Comment: Please do not recommend a core edit.